# GROUP_CONCAT() can't be used by itself?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table of products and want to select all the IDs as a comma separated string. When I run the following query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.id SEPARATOR ',') FROM products p GROUP BY 1
```

I receive the error:

> Can't group on 'GROUP_CONCAT(p.id SEPARATOR ',')'

However, if I change the query to:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(p.id SEPARATOR ',') FROM products p GROUP BY 1
```

Then it returns a row for each product with two columns, each column with a matching product ID in it. This is not what I want, but I'm showing this query to demonstrate that selecting an additional column causes the error to go away.

Why can't GROUP_CONCAT() can't be used by itself?

Comment: Get rid of the `GROUP BY 1` and it should work.

Comment: Turns out `GROUP BY 1` means to group by the 1st field from the `SELECT` clause.  See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to group *all* found rows into one, then you don't need a `GROUP BY` clause at all.

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html):

> If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.

You should be able to just do:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.id SEPARATOR ',') FROM products p
```

Note that `SEPARATOR ','` is the *default* and you can just use:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) FROM products p
```

According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) for the `SELECT` statement, you can pass a *position* to `GROUP BY` and it will group by that column.

> Columns selected for output can be referred to in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses using column names, column aliases, or column positions. Column positions are integers and begin with 1 [...] Use of column positions is deprecated because the syntax has been removed from the SQL standard.

So, `GROUP BY 1` is interpreted as `GROUP BY GROUP_CONCAT(p.id SEPARATOR ',')`, which makes no sense.

Comment: I thought aggregate functions required a `GROUP BY` clause. Thanks for educating me!

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
create table products (id int);
insert into products values (1), (2), (3);
select group_concat(id separator ',') from products;
```

Result:

```
+--------------------------------+
| group_concat(id separator ',') |
+--------------------------------+
| 1,2,3                          |
+--------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(p.id SEPARATOR ',') FROM products p GROUP BY 1
```

You are grouping by Id

If this is what you want, you can try:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.id SEPARATOR ',') FROM products p GROUP BY id
```

If you need only one row with all Ids separated by ',' you need only:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM products
```

Comment: No, I just included the query at the end to show that the error goes away when another column is selected. Isn't your second query doing the same thing as `SELECT ID from products`?

Comment: @Nate If this isn't what you need, edit your question and eplain what you need: What do you want to group?

Comment: `I have a table of products and want to select all the IDs as a comma separated string`

Comment: @Nate I edited my answer. Now I think it's what you need

Answer (score 1):

For GROUP BY to work properly, you need the column by which you will group and that need to be included in the selected fields. When you write GROUP By 1, it is actually grouping by the first column.

If you just want to group all of the rows (not by any column), you can use a dummy column which will be same for all rows. Like this :

```
SELECT 'test', GROUP_CONCAT(p.id SEPARATOR ',') FROM products p GROUP BY 1
```

Or just remove the GROUP BY at all

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.id SEPARATOR ',') FROM products p
```

Comment: Or... you could just remove the `GROUP BY 1` altogether.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Correct

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `GROUP BY` expression:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) FROM products p
```